# Add CSS Class to OL Element in QuillJS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-selectors, quill

Is there a way to set a CSS class to OL element which wraps LI elements in QuillJS. Basically what I want is to apply the CSS class which is set to one LI element when selecting the align format. Currently selecting text in a list to apply align format sets the ql-aling class to the selected list item element, which is fine, but for some special styling requirement I would like to set the ql-align class to the parent element which is either OL or UL element.
I would like to have something like this inside the editor.
`<ol class="ql-align-center"><li>item</li> </ol>`
It does not matter if the class gets set also to the LI element.

What I first tried is just using CSS to target desired elements, because what I need is to set some style on elements that are first siblings to the elements which have the ql-align class set. But I wasn't able to create a selector which would target for instance a P element that is the first next sibling to the OL element which has LI elements with the class ql-align. So if there is a way to do it by just using CSS that would be awesome.
Then I tried overriding quill functionality but I didn't manage to find a way to set the class to the OL element and to persist it.
Then I tried using plain JS to set the class to the OL element by directly manipulating the HTML, but again I couldn't get the class to persist because I guess quill rerenders the HTML on different occasions. This is what I'm currently working on, finding the places where quill rerenders the HTML so I can again apply the CSS class but this is not ideal.
So if anyone has an idea I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.